# Alternative for setting the srcObject using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webrtc, vuejs2, vuex

Setting the "src" attribute of the html video element does not work with Vue.js and Vuex:

```
<video id="myVideoEl" :src="myStreamSrc" autoplay="autoplay">
```

`myStreamSrc` is a computed value and is set in a mutation by an event handler:

```
AddStream: function (state, plMyStream) {
  state.myRTCPeerConnection.addStream(plMyStream)
  state.myStreamSrc = plMyStream
}
```

When I run my application with that code, I get the following error:

> HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported. Load of media
>   resource http://localhost:8080/[object%20MediaStream] failed.

When I do the following:

```
state.myVideoEl = document.querySelector('#myVideoEl')
state.myVideoEl.srcObject = payloadWithMyStream
```

I do not get any error and the stream is shown. The problem is, I can not use the working code snipped because the referenced elements are added later to the DOM. This code snippet does not work when I bind the html video element in a div with a `v-if` Vuex.js attribute. Then I just get "undefined" as a result (because the div element with the video element did not exist on page load).

Is there a difference between setting the `srcObject` and setting the `src` attribute? I thought that when I set `srcObject` the video element will have a `src` attribute, but it does not.

Is it possible to set the `srcObject` in the video html attribute?

For more info, please visit my theard in the Vue.js forum:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/reference-elements-when-they-rendered-with-v-if/16474/13

Comment: Have you tried `<video v-if="myStreamSrc" id="myVideoEl" :src="myStreamSrc" autoplay="autoplay">`  ?

Comment: Tried your suggestion. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<video v-if="myStreamSrc" id="myVideoEl" :srcObject ="myStreamSrc" autoplay="autoplay"> ?
```

Otherwise i would recommend you to write a component for that case:

```
var videoComponent = {
  template: '<video ref="myVideoEl" :srcObject ="myStreamSrc" autoplay="autoplay">'
  props: ['myStreamSrc']
}
Vue.component("video-component", videoComponent)
```

In the parent template

```
<video-component v-if="myStreamSrc" :myStreamSrc="myStreamSrc"></video-component>
```

OR in the parent you can just put a watcher for the srcObject which i assume to be equal to false until the correct video source gets loaded. In this case you can wait till the source target is set and then do it in the working way.

```
...
watchers:{
    myStreamSrc: function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if(!oldValue && !!newValue){
        this.nextTick(function () {
          state.myVideoEl = document.querySelector('#myVideoEl')
          state.myVideoEl.srcObject = payloadWithMyStream
        })
      }
  }
}
```

Hint:
You can use `$refs.myVideoEl` instead of `document.querySelector('#myVideoEl')` when you set `ref="myVideoEl"` to the html-element instead of `id="myVideoEl"`. This is just a sort of taste.

PS: I wrote the code in stackoverflow directly without an spellchecker...

Comment: Tried and ":srcObject ="myStreamSrc" does not work. There is not an error. It seems that it is not supported. The second and third solution will not work because setting the "srcObject" or referencing an html element by "$refs" which was added to the DOM later by "v-if" can not be found and referenced. This is my main problem.

Comment: ok then please add everything that depends on id or ref inside of an https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick function

Comment: Thank you, it works! But why I have to use the "nextTick" function? Why I can not just use "v-if", watch for changes and set the "srcObject" of the video html element after the watched variable changes to true? If I do so, the element can not be found in DOM. Why does it work with "nextTick" function, only?

Comment: NextTick ensures that the new Elements have been added to the DOM while v-if does not care about this. Everything is triggered asynchroneous. 
If my answer is correct for you please accept and rate it.
You will need nextTick in most cases like this. The docu says "Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update. This is the same as the global Vue.nextTick, except that the callback’s this context is automatically bound to the instance calling this method."

Answer (score 15):

srcObject is modifier not a html attribute, so you need to write

```
<video :srcObject.prop="myStreamSrc" autoplay/>
```

See answer from [Priansh Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5735184/priansh-shah) for a 2019 update.

Answer (score 10):

Posting an updated solution for newer versions of Vue in case anyone comes across this and runs across the same errors I did.

Update for Vue 3:

In template files, you can use `:srcObject.prop` directly. For regular HTML files, see below!

---

Updating for 2019:

```
<video :src-object.prop.camel="stream">
```

---

The first change is to bind to `srcObject` using v-bind, here’s an example with the shorthand:

```
<video :srcObject.prop="stream">
```

However `srcObject` is camel cased so in HTML it just becomes `srcobject` (lowercase) which is considered a different property and so won’t fire the video.

If you’re using Vue < 2.1, you’ll have to fire it manually using `document.getXXXXX(...).srcObject = stream`.

But if you’re using Vue v2.1+ you’re in luck as there is now an API modifier for this as well:

```
<video :src-object.prop.camel="stream">
```

`.camel` converts kebab-case to camel case, so to get `srcObject` we do the reverse and get `src-object.camel`. Combining this with `.prop` and `v-bind` we get the above syntax.

Comment: Is this still how this would be done? I have a reactive object that I am successfully loading a stream into but neither of the following binding methods seem to work:     <video id="video" v-if="stream" :srcObject.prop="stream" autoplay></video>
    <video id="video2" v-if="stream" :src-object.prop.camel="stream" autoplay></video> I can only get it to display if I query the tag directly.

Comment: This is still how it would be done! Also in Vue3, in template files, you can bind with`:srcObject` directly without the camel modifier (but you still need the camel modifier if you are binding in a regular HTML file). If you are using `reactive`, you may be running into a reactivity issue instead of a binding issue.

Comment: This also works in `petite-vue` for those interested. `:src-object.prop.camel="stream"` saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to chime in with my (similar) solution. I'm using the Nuxt framework for Vue. Setting MediaStream thru Vuex also didn't work for me. The state of the webcam being on is initiated thru a button click in a non-child component and I needed to set the mediastream for the video object in this other component.

In the method that runs when you click the button to toggle my view, as well as kick off `navigator.mediaDevices` I ended up doing this (probably not the cleanest?).

```
let constraints = (window.constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
          facingMode: "user"
        }
      });

      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then((stream) => {
          let videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
          if (this.$store.state.debug) console.log("Got stream with constraints:", constraints);
          if (this.$store.state.debug) console.log("Using video device: " + videoTracks[0].label);
          stream.oninactive = function() {
            if (this.$store.state.debug) console.log("Stream inactive");
          };
          // NOTE: this is done this way because I couldnt set it via Vuex state
          document.getElementById('user-media__source').srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.name === "ConstraintNotSatisfiedError") {
            if (this.$store.state.debug) console.log(`The resolution ${constraints.video.width.exact} "x" ${constraints.video.width.exact} px is not supported by your device.`);
          } else if (error.name === "PermissionDeniedError") {
            if (this.$store.state.debug) console.log(`Permissions have not been granted to use your camera and microphone, you need to allow the page access to your devices in order for the demo to work.`);
          }
        });
```

So since my component I need to set the source in is already created/mounted I just fired of the usual `document.getElementById('XXXX').srcObject =` and it worked like I wanted.