# How to call a function when store has data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have to create a video player object but I need the stream object to be present *before* I create the video player.

The `this.stream` is populated by vuex data store. but I find the `mounted()` and `created()` methods don't wait for store data to be present.

Here is the Player.vue component:

```
import Clappr from 'clappr';
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import * as types from '../store/types';

export default {
  name: 'streams',
  data() {
    return {
      player: null
    };
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      stream: types.STREAMS_RESULTS_STREAM
    }),

    stream() {
      return this.$store.stream;
    }
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      getStream: types.STREAMS_GET_STREAM
    })
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getStream.call(this, {
      category: this.$route.params.category,
      slug: this.$route.params.slug
    })
      .then(() => {
        this.player = new Clappr.Player({
          source: this.stream.url,
          parentId: '#player',
          poster: this.stream.poster,
          autoPlay: true,
          persistConfig: false,
          mediacontrol: {
            seekbar: '#0888A0',
            buttons: '#C4D1DD'
          }
        });
      });
  }
};
```

Is there a way to wait for `this.stream` to be present?

Comment: can you post the code of the action `types.STREAMS_GET_STREAM`?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888111/alternative-for-setting-the-srcobject/45894603#45894603 there is a solution with a watcher. That should fullfill your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subscribe on mutation event, For example if you have a mutation in your store called `setStream` you should subscribe for this mutation. Here's a code snippet of how to subscribe in mounted method.

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$store.subscribe((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'setStream') {
      // Your player implementation should be here.
    }
  })
}
```